# How to do a composer update with Laravel when lost access to private repo

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, vendor

I have a project developed with Laravel 4 and using composer. I developed my app using a composer package from a private github repo that I have since lost access to. The app works great on my localhost since the package files are still in the vendor folder, however the vendor folder does not get added to GIT so when I checkout from prod server the app is incomplete. I cannot run "composer install" from prod because it complains that my credentials to that private repo don't work anymore.

So in the event a package goes down or I loose access to a remote repo, how am I supposed to continue using composer and still use the local copy of the package still living in the vendor folder.

So ideas I thought of:

- Commit the entire vendor folder to GIT
- Setup another repo and copy the package files there and update package url in composer.json
- Copy the package files out of vendor folder and try to get them to work as part of the app folder

I can't seem to find much help searching Google. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You gave the answers yourself and I can't see any question. If a package source is gone there is no magic wand to bring it back. Btw. you can set up your own *private* repo no need to use a public one.

Comment: There are several subscription based repos (e.g. Cartalyst), so your only option is continue paying forever if you want to use one of their packages you bought?

Comment: If you want updates etc. from them then yes you will have to pay. If not you will have to stick to the version you downloaded during your subscription time I guess. But you can copy it to any private repo instead, have a look here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own